# Core Data: copy-on-write entities?

Tags: ios, entity-framework, cocoa, core-data

We need to ship a large seed data in an iOS application bundle. However the application needs to update the data from the server as required. Updates from the server needs to "overwrite" the seed data as required.

The plan is to have two persistent stores, "a" and "b", in which "a" is a read-only persistent store mounted from within the application bundle and "b" is a read-write persistent store. We need both stores to share the same model (and entities) to keep the application logic simple. Hence if an entity if modified and it was originally in store "a", the modifications should get saved in store "b" which overrides any attributes present in "a". In essence it's a "copy-on-write" paradigm.

Questions are:

- Is this achievable in Core Data? How?
- If not workable are the other alternatives for having a large seed data and yet not duplicating (a.k.a. wasting) space on the user's device?

Comment: Why is store "a" (the read-only one) needed? Can't you provide pre-populated data within the app bundle and then use only one store?

Comment: @MichałCiuba The seed data is quite large and thus copying the data from the app bundle (so that it can be written to) entails duplicating the data and it won't be "polite" for the user. Some of this seed data items would probably be outdated when the user installs it, hence the requirement of partial updates. Moreover every update of the app will need to update this data as well and we can't just overwrite an existing data file if it already contains user content.

Answer (score 0):

Save new data:

```
Store *newStoreItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Store"
                                                                        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

                newStoreItem.store_id       = [[data objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"];
                newStoreItem.lat            = [[data objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lat"];
                newStoreItem.lng            = [[data objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lng"];
```

Then when need, check it:

```
- (BOOL) isStoreExist
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

        fetchedStoreItem = [[appDelegate getStore_byID:store_id]mutableCopy];


    if ([fetchedStoreItem count] == 0)
    {
        return NO;}
    else
    {
        return YES;}
}
```

Then replace data:

```
fetchedStoreItem = [[appDelegate getStore_byID:store_id]mutableCopy];

                 Store *oldStoreItem = [fetchedStoreItem objectAtIndex:0];

                 oldStoreItem.store_id       = [[data objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"];
                 oldStoreItem.lat            = [[data objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lat"];
                 oldStoreItem.lng            = [[data objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lng"];
```